# How to update text field on button click?

Tags: java, android, button, textfield

I need help in the **MainActivity.java** coding such that **the value of the text field is stored into a variable on button click** so that i could **use it for search query later**.

The **activity_main.xml** contains the following:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:text="Search"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/SearchText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:text="Search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />
```

Could anyone suggest what the **MainActivity.java** file should contain as to recieve the text value as i am new to coding?

Answer (score 0):

Add onClick on your button

```
onClick:"btnClicked"
```

Like

```
<Button
    android:text="Search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="btnClicked" />
```

Add these code in Java file

```
public void btnClicked(View view){
     EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.SearchText);
     String value = et.getText().toString();// your edit text value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String value = SearchText.getText().toString();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Variable to store value.
String variable;

//References to the views.
Button btnClick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
EditText etText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.SearchText);

//Setting click to the button
btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final View v) {
                        // Do Your stuff.
                        variable = etText.getText().toString();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String YOUR_VARIABLE = "";

 Button btn= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



 @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
          EditText edtText = (Edittext)findViewById(R.id.SearchText);

           if(!edtText.isEmpty()){
                 YOUR_VARIABLE = edtText.getText().toString();
       }
   });
```

This will store your EditText text in your Variable
if you want to use That variable Globally you should make if `public static`

Answer (score 0):

what the **MainActivity.java** file should contain as to receive the text value as i am new to coding?
Write This Code in Your **MainActivity.java** Whatever you will give in Text field and click Button , It will update and show in Toast Message.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText et;
Button bt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.SearchText);
    bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String eText = et.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your Text is here"+eText,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });



}
```